# Ios Swift making font toggle bold, italic, boldItalic, normal without change other attributes

Tags: ios, swift, uifont, bold, italic

I am surprised, that simply setting bold and italic for existing font is so complicated in Swift.

I just want to simplify things by having following methods on font class.

I want the below methods to be added to existing font which has font-family and font-size set. I need to preserve these and change only the following.

> setBold : Shud preserve italic
>
> setItalic : Shud preserve bold
>
> setBoldItalic
>
> setNormal : remove both bold and italic
>
> removeBold : Shud preserve italic
>
> removeitalic : Shud preserve bold

I tried the below, and it's feeling like a nightmare for me using fontDescriptorWithSymbolicTraits.

Is there a simpler way of doing these in a few lines of code?

```
extension UIFont
{
    var isBold: Bool
    {
        return fontDescriptor().symbolicTraits.contains(.TraitBold)
    }

    var isItalic: Bool
    {
        return fontDescriptor().symbolicTraits.contains(.TraitItalic)
    }

    func setBold() -> UIFont
    {
        var fontDescriptorVar: UIFontDescriptor
        if(isBold){
            return self
        }
        else
        {
            fontDescriptorVar = fontDescriptor().fontDescriptorWithSymbolicTraits(.TraitBold)
        }
        return UIFont(descriptor: fontDescriptorVar, size: 0)
    }

    func setItalic()-> UIFont
    {
        var fontDescriptorVar: UIFontDescriptor
        if(isItalic) {
            return self
        }
        else
        {
            fontDescriptorVar = fontDescriptor().fontDescriptorWithSymbolicTraits(.TraitItalic)
        }
        return UIFont(descriptor: fontDescriptorVar, size: 0)
    }

    func setBoldItalic()-> UIFont
    {
        let fontDescriptorVar = fontDescriptor().fontDescriptorWithSymbolicTraits(UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits(arrayLiteral: .TraitBold, .TraitItalic))
        return UIFont(descriptor: fontDescriptorVar, size: 0)
    }

    // Things I need are

    // To set back to normal

    func setNormal()-> UIFont
    {

    }

    // Remove only bold if it's both bold and Italic

    func removeBold()-> UIFont
    {

    }

    // Remove only italic if it's both bold and Italic

    func removeitalic()-> UIFont
    {

    }
}
```

I don't want to use this which asks me the size and font as input:

```
UIFont(name "namFontFamily", size: 16)

UIFont.systemFontOfSize(16, weight: UIFontWeightLight)
```

I searched everywhere and found no simple solution matching my needs.

Comment: I think it's really important to check the font family because not all of them have bold and italic forms, are you using default fonts or did you add a new one?

Comment: I have my own list of font family which has bold and italic.
Also Text Color is also there with the font

Comment: most of the fonts have "Bold"  or "Italic" suffix so if your font names matching this pattern maybe you will construct your fonts by their names.

Comment: My methods shud be irrespective of font family, It shud be bolded like in css. Because it am trying to create a general one for all time use

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You say you want to preserve other traits, so you may need to modify some methods in your code:

```
func setBold() -> UIFont
{
    if isBold {
        return self
    } else {
        var symTraits = fontDescriptor().symbolicTraits
        symTraits.insert([.TraitBold])
        let fontDescriptorVar = fontDescriptor().fontDescriptorWithSymbolicTraits(symTraits)
        return UIFont(descriptor: fontDescriptorVar, size: 0)
    }
}
```

`setItalic()` and `setBoldItalic()` as well.

So, `removeBold()` should be something like this:

```
func removeBold()-> UIFont
{
    if !isBold {
        return self
    } else {
        var symTraits = fontDescriptor().symbolicTraits
        symTraits.remove([.TraitBold])
        let fontDescriptorVar = fontDescriptor().fontDescriptorWithSymbolicTraits(symTraits)
        return UIFont(descriptor: fontDescriptorVar, size: 0)
    }
}
```

`removeItalic()` would be similar.

But I'm not sure about `setNormal()`. You want remove all traits, or want to just remove italic and bold? Maybe you can do it yourself as you like.

Comment: This is what i was looking for, Thanks a lot. You really saved my day :-)

Comment: @ReimondHill, Please explain _not working_. As far as I test my code with Xcode 10 and iPhone sim 12.0, my code translated for Swift 4.2 works as expected.

Answer (score 7):

**These functions should have come inbuilt in Swift, but I wish they add them in upcoming versions.**

*This is for all who wants a simple solution for setting bold and italic... etc. in Swift and don't want to spend the whole night like me.*

This has following features:

> isBold
>
> isItalic
>
> setBold: Should preserve italic
>
> setItalic: Should preserve bold
>
> setBoldItalic
>
> setNormal: remove both bold and italic
>
> desetBold: Should preserve italic
>
> desetItalic: Should preserve bold
>
> toggleBold
>
> toggleItalic

```
extension UIFont
{
    var isBold: Bool
    {
        return fontDescriptor().symbolicTraits.contains(.TraitBold)
    }

    var isItalic: Bool
    {
        return fontDescriptor().symbolicTraits.contains(.TraitItalic)
    }

    func setBoldFnc() -> UIFont
    {
        if(isBold)
        {
            return self
        }
        else
        {
            var fontAtrAry = fontDescriptor().symbolicTraits
            fontAtrAry.insert([.TraitBold])
            let fontAtrDetails = fontDescriptor().fontDescriptorWithSymbolicTraits(fontAtrAry)
            return UIFont(descriptor: fontAtrDetails, size: 0)
        }
    }

    func setItalicFnc()-> UIFont
    {
        if(isItalic)
        {
            return self
        }
        else
        {
            var fontAtrAry = fontDescriptor().symbolicTraits
            fontAtrAry.insert([.TraitItalic])
            let fontAtrDetails = fontDescriptor().fontDescriptorWithSymbolicTraits(fontAtrAry)
            return UIFont(descriptor: fontAtrDetails, size: 0)
        }
    }

    func setBoldItalicFnc()-> UIFont
    {
        return setBoldFnc().setItalicFnc()
    }

    func detBoldFnc() -> UIFont
    {
        if(!isBold)
        {
            return self
        }
        else
        {
            var fontAtrAry = fontDescriptor().symbolicTraits
            fontAtrAry.remove([.TraitBold])
            let fontAtrDetails = fontDescriptor().fontDescriptorWithSymbolicTraits(fontAtrAry)
            return UIFont(descriptor: fontAtrDetails, size: 0)
        }
    }

    func detItalicFnc()-> UIFont
    {
        if(!isItalic)
        {
            return self
        }
        else
        {
            var fontAtrAry = fontDescriptor().symbolicTraits
            fontAtrAry.remove([.TraitItalic])
            let fontAtrDetails = fontDescriptor().fontDescriptorWithSymbolicTraits(fontAtrAry)
            return UIFont(descriptor: fontAtrDetails, size: 0)
        }
    }

    func SetNormalFnc()-> UIFont
    {
        return detbBoldFnc().detbItalicFnc()
    }

    func toggleBoldFnc()-> UIFont
    {
        if(isBold)
        {
            return detbBoldFnc()
        }
        else
        {
            return setBoldFnc()
        }
    }

    func toggleItalicFnc()-> UIFont
    {
        if(isItalic)
        {
            return detbItalicFnc()
        }
        else
        {
            return setItalicFnc()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Swift 3.1

```
extension UIFont{
var isBold: Bool
{
    return fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits.contains(.traitBold)
}

var isItalic: Bool
{
    return fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits.contains(.traitItalic)
}

func setBold() -> UIFont
{
    if(isBold)
    {
        return self
    }
    else
    {
        var fontAtrAry = fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits
        fontAtrAry.insert([.traitBold])
        let fontAtrDetails = fontDescriptor.withSymbolicTraits(fontAtrAry)
        return UIFont(descriptor: fontAtrDetails!, size: pointSize)
    }
}

func setItalic()-> UIFont
{
    if(isItalic)
    {
        return self
    }
    else
    {
        var fontAtrAry = fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits
        fontAtrAry.insert([.traitItalic])
        let fontAtrDetails = fontDescriptor.withSymbolicTraits(fontAtrAry)
        return UIFont(descriptor: fontAtrDetails!, size: pointSize)
    }
}
func desetBold() -> UIFont
{
    if(!isBold)
    {
        return self
    }
    else
    {
        var fontAtrAry = fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits
        fontAtrAry.remove([.traitBold])
        let fontAtrDetails = fontDescriptor.withSymbolicTraits(fontAtrAry)
        return UIFont(descriptor: fontAtrDetails!, size: pointSize)
    }
}

func desetItalic()-> UIFont
{
    if(!isItalic)
    {
        return self
    }
    else
    {
        var fontAtrAry = fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits
        fontAtrAry.remove([.traitItalic])
        let fontAtrDetails = fontDescriptor.withSymbolicTraits(fontAtrAry)
        return UIFont(descriptor: fontAtrDetails!, size: pointSize)
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way of doing this is by checking the selection of bold & italic buttons

For Bold :

```
@IBAction func bold(_ sender : UIButton){
    sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
    if sender.isSelected{
        self.textView.font = self.textView.font?.bold()
    }else{
        self.textView.font = self.textView.font?.removeBold()
    }
}
```

For Italic :

```
@IBAction func italic(_ sender : UIButton){
    sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
    if sender.isSelected{
        self.textView.font = self.textView.font?.italic()
    }else{
        self.textView.font = self.textView.font?.removeItalic()
    }
}
```

Then the UIFont extension can hold different methods for adding and removing traits

Make sure that you persist previous traits while adding new ones in withTraits method

```
extension UIFont {

//Add Traits
func withTraits(traits:UIFontDescriptor.SymbolicTraits) -> UIFont {
    let symTraits = fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits
    let descriptor = fontDescriptor.withSymbolicTraits(UIFontDescriptor.SymbolicTraits(arrayLiteral: symTraits, traits))
    return UIFont(descriptor: descriptor!, size: 0) //size 0 means keep the size as it is
}

func bold() -> UIFont {
    return withTraits(traits: .traitBold)
}

func italic() -> UIFont {
    return withTraits(traits: .traitItalic)
}

//remove traits
func withoutTraits(traits:UIFontDescriptor.SymbolicTraits) -> UIFont {
    var symTraits = fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits
    symTraits.remove([traits])
    let fontDescriptorVar = fontDescriptor.withSymbolicTraits(symTraits)
    return UIFont(descriptor: fontDescriptorVar!, size: 0)
}

func removeBold() -> UIFont {
    return withoutTraits(traits: .traitBold)
}

func removeItalic() -> UIFont {
    return withoutTraits(traits: .traitItalic)
}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

**SWIFT 3.1**

```
func changeTrait(trait: UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits) {
        let range = textView.selectedRange
        let currentAttributes = textView.textStorage.attributes(at: range.location, effectiveRange: nil)
        guard let currentFont = currentAttributes[NSFontAttributeName] as? UIFont else {
            return
        }

        let fontDescriptor = currentFont.fontDescriptor
        var changedFontDescriptor: UIFontDescriptor!


        if fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits.contains(trait) {
            let existingTraitsWithNewTrait = UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits(rawValue: fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits.rawValue & ~trait.rawValue)
            changedFontDescriptor = fontDescriptor.withSymbolicTraits(existingTraitsWithNewTrait)
        } else {
            changedFontDescriptor = fontDescriptor.withSymbolicTraits(UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits(rawValue: fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits.rawValue | trait.rawValue))
        }

        let updatedFont = UIFont(descriptor: changedFontDescriptor , size: 0)

        let newAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: updatedFont]
        textView.textStorage.beginEditing()
        textView.textStorage.setAttributes(newAttributes, range: range)
        textView.textStorage.endEditing()
 }
```

**INVOKE:**

1. **FOR BOLD:**  `changeTrait(trait: .traitBold)`
2. **FOR ITALIC:** `changeTrait(trait: .traitItalic)`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I can help you, but I think you can do this way:

```
extension UIFont {

    public static func CreateWithStyle(name: String, size: CGFloat, styles: [UIFontDescriptor.SymbolicTraits]) -> UIFont {

        let fontDescriptor = UIFontDescriptor(name: name, size: size)
        var fontAtrAry = fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits

        if styles.count > 0 {

            for style in styles {
                fontAtrAry.update(with: style)
            }
        }

        return UIFont(descriptor: fontDescriptor.withSymbolicTraits(fontAtrAry)!, size: size)
    }
}
```

I don't create a remove system because I don't think we would need it.
When we are creating a Font, we establish the styles we want and that's it.
Hope I helped.